# Dataframe does not accept results from lambda function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy-ndarray, sentiment-analysis

I am writing a sentiment analyzer with a classifier where the model, sentiment function call, and classifier function call are all working for individual lines of text. Now that I am trying to apply them to live data, somehow the lambda function's results do not get encoded in the data frame.

Please let me know if you know of any workaround.

Thank you!

Here's the code for the live data testing below:

```
#File to open
live_file  = r'C:\Users\jan.von.v.n.alcoba\Desktop\FY21 Consolidated EOC\Test_Dataset.xlsx'

#Load Spreadsheet
xl = pd.ExcelFile(live_file)

#print sheet names
print(xl.sheet_names)

#load excel file and store in dataframe
live_df = pd.read_excel(xl,sheet_name='Sheet1')
live_df

live_df['Feedback'] = live_df['Feedback'].apply(lambda x: str(x))
live_df['Sentiment'] = live_df['Feedback'].apply(lambda x: predict_sentiment(x))
live_df['Classification'] = live_df['Feedback'].apply(lambda x: predict_classification(x))
live_df
```

The results look like this:

[Code Output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUhCn.png)

This is the live_df.head() before:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X66zf.png)

This is the live_df.head() after:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2WsJ.png)

Comment: the code looks good... which one of the applies is not working? can you post a `live_df.head()` before and after calling both applies?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is extremely unclear. What is the desired result, and what is the actual result? Most of your code refers to data we don't have. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @JuanR I've posted the live_df.head() before and after.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my problem. The answer lies in the function call which only outputs a None type. The function's output needed to be returned using the return function instead of the print function so that the data frame will accept the results of lambda.

```
def predict_sentiment(text):
    twt = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([text])
    twt = pad_sequences(twt, maxlen=40, dtype='int32', value=0)
    prediction = model.predict(twt, batch_size=1,verbose=2)[0]
    if(np.argmax(prediction) == 0):
        #print("AFI")
        return "AFI"
    elif (np.argmax(prediction) == 1):
        #print("Strength")
        return "Strength"
```

Comment: And that's why we ask for minimum reproducible examples.